# Show that $R_{1} \times R_{2}$ is not the coproduct of $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ in $\mathcal{R}$

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory

Let $\mathcal{R}$ denote the category of rings.

Show that $R_{1} \times R_{2} \simeq R_{1} \oplus R_{2}$ is not the coproduct of $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ in $\mathcal{R}$.

I know if $R_{1} \times R_{2}$ together with homomorphisms $i_{R_{1}} \in \text{Hom}(R_{1},R_{1} \times R_{2})$ $i_{R_{2}} \in \text{Hom}(R_{2},R_{1} \times R_{2})$ is the coproduct then for all $A \in \text{Ob}(\mathcal{R})$ and for all $f \in \text{Hom}(R_{1},A)$ and for all $g \in \text{Hom}(R_{2},A)$ that there exists a unique homomorphism $\varphi \in \text{Hom}(R_{1} \times R_{2}, A)$ such that $\varphi \circ i_{R_{1}} = f$ and $\varphi \circ i_{R_{2}} = g$.

Should I try to show that such a $\varphi$ does not exist and if so what is a good starting point to show that $\varphi$ does not exist? Or is there a different approach to this problem? (Only hints please, no full solutions)

Comment: Universal properties of coproducts?

Comment: If this were true, how many ring morphisms would every ring have to accept from $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$?